# Three argument constructor of the Font class

Tags: java

```
Font(String name, int style, int size);
//Creates a new Font from the specified name, style and point size.
```

The second argument represents style. Like Bold, Italic, etc but how do I know which integer value represents what? I looked up the oracle docs and couldn't figure out.

Also, is the style an Enumeration variable? Because the format looks similar.

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc states

> `style` - the style constant for the `Font` The style argument is an integer bitmask that may be `PLAIN`, or a bitwise union of `BOLD` and/or `ITALIC` (for example, `ITALIC` or `BOLD|ITALIC`). If the style argument does not conform to one of the expected integer bitmasks then the style is set to `PLAIN`.

All necessary constants are `static` fields in `java.awt.Font` class.

Answer (score 0):

You use the values given [in the `Font` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html), for example:

```
final Font italic = new Font("serif", Font.ITALIC, 12);
```

Comment: Ok, if I want bold, I'll use `Font.BOLD`....but what if I want both Bold and Italic????

Comment: @BloodBrother it's a bitmask `Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD`.